# Google.useAuthRequest() from expo-auth-session successful but with authentication as null in response

Tags: android, authentication, expo, google-signin

I’m working with the expo managed workflow and was until now always using the `expoClientId` for the google log in and everything worked as expected, I got an access token back from the `Google.useAuthRequest()` response, inside `params.access_token`.

Now, when I switch to the `androidClientId` by running `expo run:android` the response from `Google.useAuthRequest()` is still successful but the `authentication` field is `null` thus the `params` object does not contain any `access_token` field. There’s a `code` field though, don’t know what that is for!?

My `androidClientId` is correct as else the response type would be `dismiss` instead of `success`.

What am I missing? Why is the response type `success` but I'm not actually authenticated?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using the current latest `expo-auth-session` version `3.7.1`

Comment: I suddenly started experiencing a similar situation, where it's working fine on web, but suddenly stopped working on iOS simulator when it was working before. Did you make any headway on this?

Comment: Did you get anywhere whith this?

Comment: Sadly I did not =(